# How to process the response data of FBSDKGraphRequest in Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, facebook-graph-api, swift3

I have integrated the FB latest SDK(non-swift) and log in is working fine.  All I need to know how do I parse the Graph response data since its not a valid JSON

Working code:

```
     func configureFacebook()
        {
            login.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"];
            login.delegate = self
        }


func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
    print("Login buttoon clicked")
    let graphRequest:FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"first_name,email, picture.type(large)"])

    graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            // Process error
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
        else
        {
            print(result)

        }
    })
}
```

With output:

```
Login button clicked
Optional({
    "first_name" = KD;
    id = 10154CXXX;
    picture =     {
        data =         {
            "is_silhouette" = 0;
            url = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/XXXn.jpg?oh=a75a5c1b868fa63XXX146A";
        };
    };
})
```

So what format should I convert the above data to get values like URL or first_name etc?

Also I tried converting to `NSDictionary` and got error:

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
        print("Login buttoon clicked")
        let graphRequest:FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"first_name,email, picture.type(large)"])

        graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if ((error) != nil)
            {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
            else
            {
                do {

                let fbResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: result as! Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
                print(fbResult.value(forKey: "name"))


                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }

            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can simply do it as follows:

```
let data:[String:AnyObject] = result as! [String : AnyObject]
print(data["first_name"]!)
```

Swift 3:

Safe unwrapping & `Any` instead of `AnyObject`

```
if let data = result as? [String:Any] {

}
```

Comment: This seems to be the simplest. Final code for me.                 let data:[String:AnyObject] = result as! [String : AnyObject]
                
                let urlData = data["picture"]?.value(forKey: "data") as! [String : AnyObject]
                let url = urlData["url"]!

Comment: Tried access profile picture like earlier, but now nil returned even though info is there: `let profilePictureURLStr = data["picture.data.url"] as? String`. Something wrong.

Comment: Are you using swiftyJSON?

Comment: Could you check my problem with code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325970/how-to-access-profile-picture-with-facebook-api-in-swift-3

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5** Code for question and issue and solution:

*Implementation:*

```
let graphRequest:GraphRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"first_name,email,picture.type(large)"])
graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
    if ((error) != nil) {
        print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
    }
    else {
        guard let rDic = result as? NSDictionary else {
            SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: "facebook Did not allowed loading email, please set that while updating profile.")
            return
        }
        print("rDic = ", rDic)
    }
})
```

*Output:*

```
rDic =  {
    email = "you@know.it";
    "first_name" = Mr. Me;
    id = #################;
    picture =     {
        data =         {
            height = 32;
            "is_silhouette" = 0;
            url = "https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=################&height=200&width=200&ext=################&hash=################";
            width = 32;
        };
    };
}
```

P.S.: Thanks to KD and Bista their question and answer helped me figure this.